# UITableViewCells not getting reused when scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm building an app where a screen should show a tableview where in the tableview first two row are two different custom cells and the rest are different custom cells. So I have did this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:
My Code:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 && !isSearchEnabled) {
         FirstRowViewCell *cell;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FirstCell";

       cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {

            // load a new cell from the nib file
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.firstCell;
            //cell.delegate = self;
            //cell.indexPath = indexPath;
            self.firstCell = nil;

        }
        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1 && !isSearchEnabled) {
        SecondRowViewCell *cell;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SecondCell";

        cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {

            // load a new cell from the nib file
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.secondCell;
            //cell.delegate = self;
            //cell.indexPath = indexPath;
            self.secondCell = nil;

        }
        return cell;
    }else {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContactCell";

    ContactTableCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {


          [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil];

        // load a new cell from the nib file

        cell = self.contactCell;
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;
        self.contactCell = nil;

    }
    return cell;}
```

but its lagging when scrolling the tableview. When I checked with the Time Profiler in instruments its showing that cellForRowAtIndexPath especially the

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

is taking much time to load which causes lag. My question is, do the cell getting reused or not, because the above line getting executed for each and every cell even we are scrolling to the top. Please help me to get through the lag problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try this may be it will helps

```
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ContactCell";

ContactCell *cell = (ContactCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


}         

return cell;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating cells that do not have the `reuseIdentifier` set. `reuseIdentifier` is a readonly property of `UITableViewCell`. What you should do instead is register the nib with the tableview, perhaps in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method of your `UIViewController`.

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ContactCell" bundle:nil];
[tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Once you do this, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return a valid cell, whether it is instantiating it or reusing it for you.

You can refer to this Apple documentation: [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib%3aforCellReuseIdentifier%3a), [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/reuseIdentifier), and [UINib](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINib).

Comment: So should I take the line [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil]; out of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @AndrewsJ Yes, once you use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`, you no longer need `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return a valid cell as long as you previously registered a nib for that identifier.